# Is it a good practice to use "ternary operation" in the "for" loop condition?

Tags: c++, for-loop, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

Is it a good practice to use ternary operation in for loop condition.
I am asking this because i have come across the situation where in ternary operation will resolve my issue in for loop condition.

For eg:

```
for( short i = 0 ; i < count ; i++ ){
   for( short j = 0 ; j < ( ( x[i] < y[i] ) ? x[i] : y[i] ) ; j++ ){ //Here I am using ternary operation at for loop condition place
       //.....
       //.....Some Code Here .......
       //.....
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks in advance for your valuable advice.

Comment: You should take out all the whitespace too.

Comment: @CrazyEddie : Thanks for your advice. Just want to know, does it make any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see any problem.

*My advice.*
1. `short` change to `int`.
2. `#define ternary`(optional).

```
#define cond(n)  (( x[n] < y[n] ) ? x[n] : y[n] )

for( int a = 0; a < count; a++)
  for( int b = 0; b < cond(a), b++)
 {

  ........code...............

 }
```

Comment: If you make it a macro, I'd rather you make it a function, seriously.

Comment: @Xeo: I will go with an inline function for the above case.

Answer (score 6):

I'd go for `min(x[i], y[i])`, just because it's clearer, but I don't see an immediate problem with your code.

Comment: Just an example shown above .. I am performing some what similar but not exactly the same. Thanks.

Comment: If you did want clearer, for the expression given `j < x[i] && j < y[i]` is worth consideration; there may be similar ways to factor your actual expression....

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would go for `min(x[i], y[i])`. However, your readability issues can be dealt with by pre-calculating the value and using it:

```
for( short i = 0 ; i < count ; i++ ){
   int jCount = ( x[i] < y[i] ) ? x[i] : y[i]; // or min equivalent
   for( short j = 0 ; j < jCount ; j++ ){ 

   }
}
```

This changes the behaviour somewhat, in that it makes the condition blind to changes to `x[i]` and `y[i]` inside the `j` loop. I am not sure if that fits your use-case or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with using the ternary operator in general, then there is no reason not to use it in your for-loop condition.  (I like the ternary operator myself, but I know some people think it's obfuscatory)

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are no issues using ternary operator , other than that it makes code not readable . But condition like this  `x[i] < y[i] ) ? x[i] : y[i]` can sometimes create problem in case you are also modifyiong `x[i] and  y[i]` insdide for loop . So i would suggest not to use unless you really know what you are doing